# Setting class-path for testing applications in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I'm developing a test tool designed for a 3rd party Java application.  Now, here's my problem:

- The 3rd party application has many nested directories in its layout, with many jars.
- It has a plugin framework that allows people to add code referencing whatever libraries they would like to use within their plugins.

When I run the test tool I'm developing, often when I use certain plugins in the 3rd party App, the test tool gives ClassNotFound exception at run time (or whatever it is).  So, I can build, but I haven't gotten all the class references I need.

Is there a way I can just add the root of the 3rd part application to my class path so IntelliJ will use all the JARs it finds in that and its sub directories when it executes?

Comment: Recursive JAR directories are not supported yet: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-40818.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been open a while and no alternative suggestions have been made, so closing with @CrazyCoder's comment as the answer.

The following link reports this lack of functionality; it may be addressed in newer versions of IDE:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-40818